# How to Setup Redux in React without Immutable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I learned how to Redux with [Teropa's incredible tutorial](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html). However, his implementation uses Immutable and, while awesome, is something I want to remove from my current app's build. I'm trying to figure out how to maintain the following without relying on Immutable. I somehow need to modify `reducer.js` to take out Immutable, but the exported function keeps failing without `state = Map()`.

Index.jsx

```
store.dispatch({
  type: 'SET_STATE',
  state: { ... }
});
```

action_creators.js

```
export function setState(state) {
  return {
    type: 'SET_STATE',
    state
  };
}
```

reducer.js

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';

function setState(state, newState) {
  return state.merge(newState);
}
export default function(state = Map(), action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'SET_STATE':
    return setState(state, action.state);
  }
  return state;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to replace your `Map` with a standard JavaScript object and use `Object.assign` to merge things into it. I'd recommend reading the [Reducers chapter in the official Redux tutorial](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) - it takes you through this step by step.

Answer (score 1):

```
function setState(state, newState) {
  return {
    ...state,
    ...newState
  };
}
export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'SET_STATE':
    return setState(state, action.state);
  }
  return state;
```

Check how I use it in my state management library https://github.com/nosovsh/reduceless/blob/master/src/wrapReducerWithSetGlobalState.js#L9